# Passing data to function. What is the better way?

Tags: php

Way 1:

```
public $foo = 1;
function(){
   return $this->foo+1;
}
```

Way 2:

```
// with $foo = 1 in other function
function($foo){
    return $foo+1;
}
```

Sorry for a 'dumb' question, someone can tell me what is the better way?

Comment: it depend on different type of situation that which one is preferred in which scenario.And both have completely different scopes

Comment: So it all depends on the variable scope? If both functions are in same class and they both can access `$foo`, then you can use first method, if the function can't access `$foo` then you should send it to the function as a parameter, there's no "better" way.

Comment: @PaulKaram, thank you, I understood.
Thank AlivetoDie too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second way is better and it is more canonical than first one. For more information please read this doc http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php